# How to group pandas DataFrame by periods?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some financial data (example):

```
prices

                             open_price. high.   low.    close_price
2018-09-03 00:00:00+00:00    103.24      103.77  102.95  103.89 
2018-09-04 00:00:00+00:00    103.89      104.10  103.50  103.95
2018-09-05 00:00:00+00:00    103.95      104.20  103.90  104.15
2018-09-06 00:00:00+00:00    104.15      104.56  103.50  104.20
(...)
2018-09-19 00:00:00+00:00    108.42      108.85  108.19. 108.60
2018-09-20 00:00:00+00:00    108.60      108.89  108.40  108.75
```

I was trying to group this data by, let's say, 2 days. If I use

```
prices.resample('2B', closed='left', label='left').first()
```

The financial date would look like this:

```
                             open_price. high.   low.    close_price
2018-09-03 00:00:00+00:00    103.24      103.77  102.95  103.89
2018-09-05 00:00:00+00:00    103.95      104.20  103.90  104.15
(...)
2018-09-19 00:00:00+00:00    108.42      108.85  108.19. 108.60
```

I'm looking for a way to do this: Date `2018-09-03` would take the open price of `2018-09-03`, the low and the high of `2018-09-03` and `2018-09-04` and finally the close price of `2018-09-04`... The next date would be `2018-09-05`, taking the open of `2018-09-05`, low and high of `2018-09-05` and `2018-09-06` and finally the close of `2018-09-06`.

It should look something like this:

```
                             open_price. high.   low.    close_price
2018-09-03 00:00:00+00:00    103.24      104.10  102.95  103.95 
2018-09-05 00:00:00+00:00    103.95      104.56  103.50  104.20
(...)
2018-09-19 00:00:00+00:00    108.42      108.89  108.19. 108.60
```

Is there an easy way of doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `resample` with `agg`

```
d={'open_price.':'first','high.':'max','low.':'min','close_price':'last'}
df.resample('2B', closed='left', label='left').agg(d)
Out[1031]: 
            open_price.   high.    low.  close_price
2018-09-03       103.24  104.10  102.95       103.95
2018-09-05       103.95  104.56  103.50       104.20
```